# Why in Objective-C, no floating point error is seen as in other languages?

Tags: objective-c

In Ruby or Python, there was some case where `2.0` will print out as `1.99999999999` (or something like that).  It is said to be floating point inaccuracy.

In Objective-C, I don't see it happening so far... does Objective-C handle floating point error a lot better?

The reason is that, if we have such a call:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 
                           size.width * scaleFactor, size.height * scaleFactor, 
                           8, size.width * scaleFactor * 4, colorSpace, 
                           kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

and `scaleFactor` is a float or double (usually having a value of `1.0` or `2.0`), then if there is any floating point error that make `1536.0` to become `1535` after converting to an integer, it could be an issue.  If it is the size of a bitmapContext, it is less of an issue because 1 pixel less wide isn't a big deal, but if it is a size of data buffer, supplied to `malloc`, then the size of `123456.0`, if converted to `123455`, then it can be an issue, because it can cause bad memory access (segmentation fault or data contamination).

Comment: I don't believe there is any sort of difference. You're probably just lucky.

Comment: so I think the recommendation is to cast `scaleFactor` to integer first, and then do integer arithmetics, or... use `iScaleFactor` which is an integer type...

Comment: but then could there be any cast where casting a `2.0` float or double to integer will become `1`?  (the floor of `1.99999999999` is `1`)

Comment: I'd suggest rounding your floating point numbers before converting them to integers (unless it's in a place where you want 1.999 to convert to 1 instead of 2).

Comment: The fact is, however that `2.0` is completely representable by a IEEE floating point number, thus If dealing with whole numbers, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Richard what about `3.0` or `4.0`, and ... do you mean all integers that are within a certain range can be represented completely in Objective-C?  Do you have the doc or reference?

Comment: @動靜能量 no, but 2.0 is a power of 2. All powers of 2 up to `2^128 - 1` are defined to be exact. If you are really worried, use a `long double`, with `128` bits of data stored.